# How to merge two Input of type=range by css style?

Tags: html, css

I have two input of type="range". I want to merge the two.

I'd like to make the double slider, however, if I position two elements on top of one another, only the top one is accepting mouse clicks. I do not wish to use any external library to do it. I did it by **css** style but the main problem is that it does not work in Mozilla browser and IE. It just works in chrome browser and I think it is because of pointer-events: none; which does not been run in Mozilla browser. Any idea?

```
**css :**
.price-slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price-slider input {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.price-slider input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    pointer-events: all;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    outline: 0;
    height: 24px;
    widows: 24px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

**HTML:**
<div class="price-slider">
    <input value="0" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="1" type="range" />
    <input value="100" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="1" type="range" />
</div>
```

Comment: that is not for pointer events, that is not working because you are using only webkit and that working in only safari and chrome

Comment: Thanks @ Nisharg Shah for your comment. I do not think so because I added this code to My css but nothing happend

Comment: `.price-slider input::-moz-slider-thumb{pointer-events: all; position: relative; z-index: 1; outline: 0; height: 24px; widows: 24px; border-radius: 12px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid black; -webkit-appearance: none;}`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first. In addition, the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: but @Rob that not create problem, firefox have problem in range but developers will fix soon

Comment: Yes @Rob.I do not it would be the problem. It works correctly in Mozilla but not in firefox .

Comment: mozila and firebox both are same

Comment: @NishargShah Thinking invalid markup will not cause you issues is an issue in itself.

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean It works correctly in Chrome but not in firefox:|

Comment: @Rob HTML is markup language and invalid syntax ignored by HTML but for that case this is not problem

Comment: @NishargShah Browsers are required to do the best they can with invalid HTML. It is NOT ignored unless they can't figure it out. In any case, you are only hoping the browser guesses correctly at your intentions and one should never base their markup on hopes and dreams.

Comment: @Rob you are right, i don't denied your opinion but in that case, problem is not coming from HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should fix your problem but for information, `pointer-events` property works in firefox too without any prefix.

```css
.price-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-slider input {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.price-slider input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 0;
  height: 24px;
  widows: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.price-slider input::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 0;
  height: 24px;
  widows: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input::-moz-range-track {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-slider">
    <input value="0" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="1" type="range">
    <input value="100" min="0" value="100" max="100" step="1" type="range">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nisharg Shah. It works, but as you can see  one input is under another input. Can we do something to look better? and also the space between two handlers can be recognized by coloring it?

Comment: Ok @Nisharg Shah.Thanks.